How do I deploy Wagtail CMS to Ionos Standard Web Hosting
I have tried to deploy Wagtail CMS to Ionos Standard hosting using the instructions at How can I deploy Django App to 1and1 (ionos) but I am just getting an internal server error.
Any ideas how I can go about doing this?
I have the following in wavecruiseclub/cgi-bin/application.fcgi:
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
        
        import os
        import sys
        import traceback
        
        home = '(htdocs location)/htdocs/wavecruiseclub'
        try:        
            project = os.path.join(home, 'wavecruiseclub')
            # Add a custom Python path.
            sys.path.insert(0, project)
        
            # Switch to the directory of your project.
            os.chdir(project)
        
            # Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
            os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "wavecruiseclub.settings"
        
            from django_fastcgi.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
            from django.core.servers.basehttp import get_internal_wsgi_application
        
            wsgi_application = get_internal_wsgi_application()
            runfastcgi(wsgi_application, method="prefork", daemonize="false", minspare=1, maxspare=1, maxchildren=1)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(stdout)
            with open(os.path.join(home, 'tmp/error.log'), 'w') as fp:
        traceback.print_exc(file = fp)

I also have set up the .bashrc, .bash_profile and .htaccess files as detailed in the instructions.
